# Programmatically dismiss Bluetooth system alert dialog?

Tags: android, bluetooth

My app detects whether Bluetooth is disabled and triggers a system alert dialog (to enable Bluetooth) through:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE), 1711);
```

It is, however, also possible to enable Bluetooth through the notification bar and when Bluetooth is enabled there the system alert dialog is still shown.

**Can I somehow dismiss this dialog or remind Android to finish the activity and return the result (which is successful in this case) when the user enables Bluetooth through the notification bar?**

Comment: You should see a system pop-up for permission to use bluetooth. what version of Android do you use ? please add a screenshot of the pop-up

Comment: The popup is Android native and localized. It says (roughly translated to English): "X  requests Bluetooth to be turned on" with two options: Cancel/Dismiss and Allow

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to programmatically dismiss the Bluetooth system alert dialog you see on Android 9+

However, you can avoid the system alert dialog by enabling Bluetooth programatically, at least on Android 8 and less:

```
final BluetoothAdapter ba = BluetoothManagerCompat.getAdapter(yourActivity);
ba.enable();
```

Comment: That was not the question. I want to dismiss the native dialog to.enable Bluetooth (since Bluetooth is already enabled)